# Python Flask, how to update status in twitter using python rauth - oauth?

Tags: python, twitter, flask, oauth

I have implemented Twitter OAuth using Python Rauth.

but I dont know how to update users status in Twitter using Rauth?

Is there any ways to solve this ?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem using Python-twitter v3.3

First, installed python-twitter module. 
    pip install python-twitter

And these are my current codes.

```html
....
import twitter
..
CONSUMER_KEY = app.config['OAUTH_CREDENTIALS']['twitter'].get('consumer_key')
CONSUMER_SECRET = app.config['OAUTH_CREDENTIALS']['twitter'].get('consumer_secret')

api = twitter.Api(
                    consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
                    consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
                    access_token=oauth_token.access_token,
                    access_token_secret=oauth_token.access_token_secret)
api.PostUpdate(status='This is test tweet', media='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150')
```